Error : Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. in monodevelop
i'm trying to connect my gtk#2.0 app to a database. so theres a button, when the button clicked, it should fetching my database, but then an error appearing.error image. i'm using mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.6-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper, monodevelop version 7.8.4 build 2, mono Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.200 (tarball Tue Jul 11 21:32:10 UTC 2023)
heres my MainWindow.cs
using System;
using Gtk;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Button btnFetchData;
    private TextView textView;

    public MainWindow() : base("GTK# MariaDB Fetch Example")
    {
        // Set window properties
        SetDefaultSize(400, 300);
        SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);

        // Create a button to fetch data
        btnFetchData = new Button("Fetch Data");
        btnFetchData.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

        // Create a TextView to display results
        textView = new TextView();

        // Use a vertical box to layout the button and textview
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.PackStart(btnFetchData, false, false, 0);
        vbox.PackStart(textView, true, true, 0);

        Add(vbox);

        // Show all UI elements
        ShowAll();
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Connect to MariaDB and fetch data
        string connStr = "server=localhost;" + "port=3306;" + "user id=root; " + "password=halonamasayafauzy;" + "database=MonoPeople;" + "SslMode=none";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            // Clear existing text
            textView.Buffer.Clear();

            // Display results in TextView
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // Pastikan hanya membaca kolom yang ada, dan lakukan pengecekan NULL
                string id = rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("id")) ? "NULL" : rdr["id"].ToString();
                string name = rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("name")) ? "NULL" : rdr["name"].ToString();

                string row = $"ID: {id}, Name: {name}\n";
                textView.Buffer.Text += row;
            }

            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textView.Buffer.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Maincoy()
    {
        Application.Init();
        new MainWindow();
        Application.Run();
    }
}


i'm just trying to connect my gtk#2.0 app to a database in with mariadb-server. i'm using debian 12. anything will be appreciated. thanks!
